# Non-tree structure peer to peer tikz mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

All the examples of creating mindmaps with tikz use a tree approach: the parent node is in the middle, which has smaller children, which have smaller children, etc.

Is it possible to create peer to peer mindmaps, i.e. not a tree structure, but one that has multiple nodes at the same level in the ancestry tree. E.g. something like this:

[image]

Where nodes A, B and C are all the same size in are fully connected to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using Tik*Z* with the `mindmaps` library. But you have to draw the connections between the first-level nodes manually:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,concept color=black]

  \node[concept,fill=blue!30] (A) at (0,0) {A}
   child[grow=200] {node[concept,fill=blue!20] (Aa) {a}}
   child[grow=240] {node[concept,fill=blue!20] (Ab) {b}};

  \node[concept,fill=red!30] (B) at (5,5) {B}
   child[grow=20] {node[concept,fill=red!20] (Ba) {a}}
   child[grow=160] {node[concept,fill=red!20] (Bb) {b}};

  \node[concept,fill=green!30] (C) at (10,0) {C}
   child[grow=340] {node[concept,fill=green!20] (Ca) {a}}
   child[grow=300] {node[concept,fill=green!20] (Cb) {b}};

  \path
   (A) to[circle connection bar] (B)
   (B) to[circle connection bar] (C) 
   (A) to[circle connection bar] (C);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions on this forum, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144828/121799), which only require minor modifications.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\def\colorLeft{green!50!yellow!70!red!30!blue}
\def\colorRight{orange}
\def\colorTop{red!80!blue!80}
\begin{tikzpicture}[small mindmap, outer sep=0pt, text=black]
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144828/121799
\begin{scope}[concept color=\colorRight]
\node (right) at (-30:3) [concept] {Right}
  [clockwise from=0]
  child { node[concept] {R.1} }
  child { node[concept] {R.2} }
;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[concept color=\colorLeft]
\node (left) at (210:3) [concept] {Left}
  [counterclockwise from=180]
  child { node[concept] {L.1}  }
  child { node[concept] {L.2} }
;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[concept color=\colorTop]
\node (top) at (90:3) [concept] {Top}
  [counterclockwise from=53]
  child { node[concept] {T.1}  }
  child { node[concept] {T.2} }
;
\end{scope}


\path (left) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (\colorLeft) to (\colorRight)] (right) ;
\path (left) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (\colorLeft) to (\colorTop)] (top) ;
\path (top) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (\colorTop) to (\colorRight)] (right) ;


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]