# Mindmap circle connection bar drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds}

%\tikzset{concept/.append style={fill={none}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    outer sep=0pt, small mindmap,
    concept color=pink,
    every node/.style={concept}, 
    root/.style    = {concept color=pink,
    }, 
    ]
    \node[root,  anchor=center, minimum size=2.2cm, text width=2.2cm ] {A}
    [clockwise from=120] 

    child[concept color=blue!50,]{
        node[concept] (d) {D} 
        [counterclockwise from=30]
        child { node[concept color=blue!25] (e){E}
            child[counterclockwise from=35] { node[concept color=blue!12.5] (f){F}}
        }
    }
    child[concept color=orange!50] {
        node[concept, ] (h) {H}
        [counterclockwise from=0]
        child { node[concept color = orange!25, sibling angle=120] (i) {I}}
    }
    ;
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144828/38244
    \path (d) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!50) to (blue!25)] (e);
    \path (e) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!25) to (blue!12.5)] (f);
    \path (h) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (orange!50) to (orange!25)] (i);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

It gives the mindmap:

[image]

However, if you look closely, you'll see a drawing on node `E`, `F` (highlighted in yellow):
[image]

I tried to remove it by setting `draw=none` to the `\path`, but it does not work. Anyone knows how to remove these lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue is that you do not add the `concept color=` at the optimal place. If you add it to `child` instead of `node`,

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds}

%\tikzset{concept/.append style={fill={none}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    outer sep=0pt, small mindmap,
    concept color=pink,
    every node/.style={concept}, 
    root/.style    = {concept color=pink,
    }, 
    ]
    \node[root,  anchor=center, minimum size=2.2cm, text width=2.2cm ] {A}
    [clockwise from=120] 

    child[concept color=blue!50,]{
        node[concept] (d) {D} 
        [counterclockwise from=30]
        child[concept color=blue!25] { node (e){E}
            child[counterclockwise from=35,concept color=blue!12.5] { node (f){F}}
        }
    }
    child[concept color=orange!50] {
        node[concept, ] (h) {H}
        [counterclockwise from=0]
        child[concept color = orange!25] { node[sibling angle=120] (i) {I}}
    }
    ;
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144828/38244
%   \begin{scope}[on background layer]
%     \path (d) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!50) to (blue!25)] (e);
%     \path (e) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!25) to (blue!12.5)] (f);
%     \path (h) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (orange!50) to (orange!25)] (i);
%   \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

which is already pretty good. However, if you look *very* closely, you may see a tiny gap

[image]

**This gap is not there when viewed with acroread.**

If you now reinstall your connections, i.e. activate

```
\path (e) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!25) to (blue!12.5)] (f);
```

then this gap is gone when viewed with *preview*, likewise for the other connections. Under *acroread*, this gap was not there in the first place.

**ADDENDUM**: This suggests that these connecting bars are not needed at all, at least if you use *acroread* to view the mindmap. However, this is not quite true, you will need them to draw *additional* connections that are not part of the original mindmap hierarchy, e.g.

```
\draw (h) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (orange!50) to (blue!12.5)] (f);
```

[image]

Under acroread I get a spotless additional connection. Note that I used `\draw` instead of `\path` to get a better result.