# Remove white strip in mind maps using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Following the Tikz/PGF document, I am creating a mind map with 3 child nodes as can be seen in the MWE below. I want to remove the white strip in the connections between the node and the child nodes. There is a brief mention of the problem in the documentation, so I changed the `decorations` accordingly. However the problem still persists. Any advice?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing,chains,snakes,positioning,angles,quotes}  
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={level distance = 22mm}}
\tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=0.5}}

 \tikz[mindmap,concept color=blue!60,decoration={start radius=1cm,
                   end radius=.5cm,amplitude=2mm,angle=20}]
  \node [concept] {Main}
child[concept color=red!60,grow=240] {node[concept] {Child1}}
child[concept color=green!60,grow=120] {node[concept] {Child2}}
child[concept color=orange!60,grow=0]  {node[concept] {Child3}};
\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447318/36296 could help

Comment: Which viewer are you using? I confirm the gaps with preview but there are none when viewed with acroread. IMO this is a so-called viewer issue. You *could* redraw the connection as done in the link provided by @samcarter but I don't think it is necessary. Just using acroread to print this out should work, I think.

Comment: @marmot, I'm using Acrobat reader. The issue can be seen when zooming into the image. I'll follow the link to see how to adapt it.

Comment: I want to add that the issue arises since I tried to reduce the distance between the node and the child.

Comment: @Sid Please do not follow the link, this will be at best a workaround. In that question the OP placed the color at the wrong position. You are doing it correctly. I guess on the long run one may have to really try to understand how the connections are drawn in detail and try to fix them, something that I avoided to do so far. What precisely do you mean by `I tried to reduce the distance between the node and the child`?

Comment: Adapting `\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={level distance = 22mm}}` and `\tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=0.5}}` changes the relative position of the nodes of the mindmap

Comment: Yes, it might be the `\tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=0.5}}`. Can't you just scale the whole picture?

Comment: Indeed I could. I just aesthetically preferred changing the distance.